# What does Venom's "that" refer to?

Tags: venom

In *Venom Let There Be Carnage* (2021), Eddie and Anne meet each other at L'Araignée. He discovered that she is engaged to
Dr Dan not him:

> Anne: You could just say, "Congratulations, I'm happy for you." You
> know, like two people  who still care enough about each other to lie
> so that the other one doesn't feel like  complete shit. Maybe we could
> do that version of this?
>
> Eddie: No, I am... I am happy for you, Anne. Congratulations.
>
> Anne: Thank you.
>
> Venom: **That** was going to be us, Eddie!

What does Venom's "that" refer to?

Comment: That that, that that that refers to is the engagement. (Yes, the preceding is *absolutely* a valid sentence.)

Comment: He says they should be be engaged not Dan. Asking about a word sounds like something for ELL.se

Comment: Anyone can down vote for any reason, and that's fine. But language questions are on-topic, as discussed here. https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11626/is-it-reasonable-to-ask-about-the-meaning-of-phrases-in-a-science-fiction-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'That' here refers to the whole situation described in the proceeding discussion. Venom is saying it could be Eddie and Venom who were going to marry Anne.